# Read file from multiple encoding in c#

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

ENV: C#, VStudio 2013, 4.5 Framework, Winforms, nHapi 2.3 dll

I really need help on this. I have tried soo many things and did alot of research with my best friend google ;-). But no luck.

I'm building a HL7 sender tools and I'm reading files from a folder. My files come from multiple sources and I found that they have different encoding : I have open them with notepadd++ and they can be ainsi, utf8 et utf8 witout BOM. My files also contains special caracters like é,à,ç,ô, .... but they always put weird caracter when I read the file with this line : var hl7message = File.ReadAllText(e.Node.Name);

**The only time I don't have any problem is when the source file is encoded in UTF8 with the BOM.**

Is there a way that no matter what the source file encoding is, I can alway read the file in a string and have the special caracter show correctly.

This is the main portion of my code :

```
var hl7message = File.ReadAllText(FileName);
var llphl7message = Convert.ToChar(11).ToString() + newmessage + Convert.ToChar(28).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(13).ToString();

// Get the size of the message that we have to send.
Byte[] bytesSent = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(llphl7message);
Byte[] bytesReceived = new Byte[256];

// Create a socket connection with the specified server and port.
Socket s = ConnectSocket(txtParamServer.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtParamPort.Text));
// If the socket could not get a connection, then return false.
if (s == null)
{
                    txtLog.Text = txtLog.Text + "[" + DateTime.Now + "] [ERR] Serveur " + txtParamServer.Text + " sur le port " + txtParamPort.Text + " est non disponible" + "\r\n";
                    return false;
}

// Send message to the server.
s.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0);
```

Thank you for you help
Sorry for the bad english : not my main language

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the StreamReader class. It has a parameter for "detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks".

```
            string result;
            using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("FILENAME", true))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```